# Java Api for distribuited systems communication

Tags: distributed-computing, software-distribution, jgroups

We're looking for some java api to use as middleware/bus to make java processes running on different hosts communicate. 
The scenario is the following:
- we have a web application we want to use to monitor the different java processes running on different hosts
- we want all the different processes to be able to communicate with the web application, pushing their own status to the central web app
- we want the web app to be able to poll the different processes in order to receive updates about their status

We were thinking to use something like jgroups, while we wouldn't like to use jms.
Do anyone suggest any alternative? Even better if advantages/disavantages are highlighted..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a messaging system such as RabbitMQ http://www.rabbitmq.com/ or ActiveMQ http://activemq.apache.org/ .  Rabbit has been gaining a lot of popularity recently and is straightforward to use (see http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html for example).